# Error when adding selenium android driver jar in TestNG. Cannot find class file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, testng

I'm writing a test class for an Android App, but I keep getting the error code "The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.openqa.selenium.html5.BrowserConnection. Fix the build path then try building this project." each time I try to add the selenium Android driver jar file to the project. I need the Android driver to use the TestNG with Appium properly, otherwise Appium can't find elements on the page when testing. The Code:

```
package appiumTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class TestCase {

    public class NewTest {
        WebDriver driver = new AndroidDriver();
        @BeforeClass
        protected void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

            //Tells the program what device is used
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new 

            DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
            capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "4.2.2"); 
            capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Emulator");
            capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
            //Tells the program what app is being run
            capabilities.setCapability("appPackage",                                 
   "com.android.testapp2");

    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
   "com.android.testapp2.MainActivity    ");
     driver = (AndroidDriver) new RemoteWebDriver(new
             URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        }
        @Test
        public void test() {
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
               userName.sendKeys("a");
            WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("btnEnter"));
    button.click();
        };
        @AfterClass
        protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

            driver.quit();
        }

    }


}
```

Here's the code of the pom.xml file I'm trying to edit:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"        

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    

xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TestProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestProject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I don't see anywhere to put a dependency, and I'm not even sure if that's what I'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: What build tool (Maven / Gradle) are you using? Can you share (add) the configuration of the build tool? Seems you need to add Selenium dependency.

Comment: Maven. I found the Selenium dependency and the pom.xml file to edit, but it's not editable.

Comment: You should have a local own editable pom.xml file. Sounds you found a pom.xml inside some dependency jar, as these are and should not edited. As they come with a particular jar. Can you add your pom.xml to the question here?

Comment: @Verhagen pom.xml code is added to the original post. I was trying to edit a pom.xml in the jar file as you said, because I wasn't sure where else to put the dependency since it was specifically for that jar. I don't even know if I have the right dependency.

Comment: I'll check it later. Q: What IDE (Eclipse/IntelliJ/etc) are you using, just handy to know, when I need to explain things.

Answer (score 0):

*Ok, this should get you going again, I think.*

The improvements made in the `pom.xml`:

- No dependencies where definded, so added the required onces

  - testng v6.9.8
  - selenium-java v2.39.0
  - selenium-android-driver v2.39.0
    *Remark 1: The Selenium Java and Android libraries, should be of the same version (for as far as I know, otherwise it can give issues).*
    _Remark 2:_The Selenium Android library, is an older library. It should actually be replaced by the newer one [Selendroid](http://selendroid.io/). Therefor also some import would change.
- Improved the `<groupid>` and `<artifactid>`, these are standard in lower case, and should represent some logical *and unique* thing. Maybe you store you project on bitbucket, or github, then a logical group id would start with `com.github.<your-github-account-id>.<name-of-the-project>`.
- Removed the `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>`
- Created a directory `src/test/java`
- Added the package name `appiumTest` to that test source directory
- added the class `TestCase` in that package.

The Maven project file `pom.xml`:

**Remark** Below is the correct Maven starting tag `<project>` shown, as it should be used in the `pom.xml`. But StackOverflow, does not show it correctly, when the starting tag has attributes.

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Below the corrected `pom.xml`, but without the correct starting tag.

```xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.organisation.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-selenium</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <!--
            <version>2.48.2</version>
            -->
            <version>2.39.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-android-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.39.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source />
                    <target />
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The improvements made in the class `TestCase`:

- No need to use of inner class `NewTest`, so removed it.
- Removed initialization of field `driver`, as it gets initialized in the `@BeforeClass` method.
- Added check in the `@AfterClass`, only call `driver.quit()`, when driver is initalize.

The class `TestCase`:

```
package appiumTest;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

public class TestCase {
    WebDriver driver; // = new AndroidDriver();

    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

        // Tells the program what device is used
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "4.2.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Emulator");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        // Tells the program what app is being run
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.testapp2");

        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity",
                "com.android.testapp2.MainActivity");
        driver = (AndroidDriver) new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName"));
        userName.sendKeys("a");
        WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("btnEnter"));
        button.click();
    };

    @AfterClass
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

**Possible Improvements**

- Correct the package name (currently `appiumTest`), but that is not inline with the nameing convention, all lower case, seperate with a dot `.`. And something meaningful, similar as to the Maven group-id. Sp start with `com.github.<your-github-account-id>.<name-of-the-project>`
- Give the class `TestCase` a better name
- Update to Selendroid, then also update the Selenium Java version